# Does Spring Boot Neo4j support heterogenous graphs? How?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, neo4j

The [Neo4j doco](https://neo4j.com/docs/ogm-manual/current/tutorial/#tutorial:annotations:relationships) shows that we can have heterogenous graphs (nodes of different types):

```
@NodeEntity
class Department {
    String name;

    @Relationship(type = "CURRICULUM")
    Set<Subject> subjects;
}

@NodeEntity
class Subject {
    String name;

    @Relationship(type="CURRICULUM", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    Department department;
}
```

However, the [Spring Boot Guide on using Neo4j](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/) only shows a homogenous example.

The problem that the example leaves me with is that it shows this as the way of setting up the repository:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

    Person findByName(String name);
}
```

This results in a repository that only supports operations with `Person` parameters - IE the graph has to be homogenous.

How do you make it work for a heterogenous graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support multiple entities, you just need to define a separate `CrudRepository` interface per entity.

Comment: So this seems to mean I have to "wire up" (using DI) and "pass around" a "repository interface" object for each entity type?  And `entity_type_repo.save(entity)` using the correct one for each type?   Is that right?   (Sounds kinda cumbersome?)

Comment: You can use repositories either with `DI` or without (AKA "standalone"). See [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances).

Comment: Right.  What I discovered is that I don't need to have a save method available for all entity types, because some will just get saved automatically when they are linked.